# LINQ query not correct for EF when using include with multiple level

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I get the following exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The column 'fkidModelHardware1' was specified multiple times for 'Join4'.
>   The column 'fkidModelHardware2' was specified multiple times for 'Join7'.

With SQL Profiler I've intercepted the query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Limit1].[idAssetHardware] AS [idAssetHardware], 
    [Limit1].[UID] AS [UID], 
    [Limit1].[fkidAssetHardwareParent] AS [fkidAssetHardwareParent], 
    [Limit1].[fkidAssetHardwareParentPermanent] AS [fkidAssetHardwareParentPermanent], 
    [Limit1].[AssetTag] AS [AssetTag], 
    [Limit1].[SerialNumber] AS [SerialNumber], 
    [Limit1].[Hostname] AS [Hostname], 
    [Limit1].[Alias] AS [Alias], 
    [Limit1].[fkidModel] AS [fkidModel], 
    [Limit1].[fkidRoom] AS [fkidRoom], 
    [Limit1].[Nomad] AS [Nomad], 
    [Limit1].[ManyUsers] AS [ManyUsers], 
    [Limit1].[fkidDepartment] AS [fkidDepartment], 
    [Limit1].[fkidUserAD] AS [fkidUserAD], 
    [Limit1].[fkidStatus] AS [fkidStatus], 
    [Limit1].[EndOfLeaseDate] AS [EndOfLeaseDate], 
    [Limit1].[fkidOwner] AS [fkidOwner], 
    [Limit1].[Suspect] AS [Suspect], 
    [Limit1].[LastChecked] AS [LastChecked], 
    [Limit1].[Remark] AS [Remark], 
    [Limit1].[LastModifiedBy] AS [LastModifiedBy], 
    [Limit1].[LastModifiedOn] AS [LastModifiedOn], 
    [Limit1].[fkidAssetService] AS [fkidAssetService], 
    [Limit1].[SCCM_ResourceID] AS [SCCM_ResourceID], 
    [Limit1].[fkidOs] AS [fkidOs], 
    [Limit1].[fkidProfile] AS [fkidProfile], 
    [Limit1].[InvDate] AS [InvDate], 
    [Limit1].[fkidNetwork] AS [fkidNetwork], 
    [Limit1].[fkidAssetServiceWarranty] AS [fkidAssetServiceWarranty], 
    [Limit1].[MacAdress] AS [MacAdress], 
    [Limit1].[WarrantyExtensionYears] AS [WarrantyExtensionYears], 
    [Limit1].[fkidLeasingContract] AS [fkidLeasingContract], 
    [Limit1].[SAP] AS [SAP], 
    [Limit1].[Contact] AS [Contact], 
    [Limit1].[idModel] AS [idModel], 
    [Limit1].[ModelName] AS [ModelName], 
    [Limit1].[PartNumber] AS [PartNumber], 
    [Limit1].[fkidBrand] AS [fkidBrand], 
    [Limit1].[fkidCategory] AS [fkidCategory], 
    [Limit1].[fkidFamily] AS [fkidFamily], 
    [Limit1].[fkidType] AS [fkidType], 
    [Limit1].[Picture] AS [Picture], 
    [Limit1].[RequestSerialNumber] AS [RequestSerialNumber], 
    [Limit1].[AssetSuffix] AS [AssetSuffix], 
    [Limit1].[BufferStock] AS [BufferStock], 
    [Limit1].[SlavePermanent] AS [SlavePermanent], 
    [Limit1].[ImportantForInv] AS [ImportantForInv], 
    [Limit1].[ExcludeFromDashboard] AS [ExcludeFromDashboard], 
    [Limit1].[DefaultWarrantyLengthYears] AS [DefaultWarrantyLengthYears], 
    [Limit1].[ToFollowUp] AS [ToFollowUp], 
    [Limit1].[ForceShowProfile] AS [ForceShowProfile], 
    [Limit1].[ForceShowSvcDetails] AS [ForceShowSvcDetails], 
    [Limit1].[idProductCode] AS [idProductCode], 
    [Limit1].[ProductDescription] AS [ProductDescription], 
    [Limit1].[Category] AS [Category], 
    [Limit1].[NeedDelivery] AS [NeedDelivery], 
    [Limit1].[fkidDealer] AS [fkidDealer], 
    [Limit1].[fkidModelHardware] AS [fkidModelHardware], 
    [Limit1].[fkidSoftwareCatalog] AS [fkidSoftwareCatalog], 
    [Limit1].[fkidServiceCatalog] AS [fkidServiceCatalog], 
    [Limit1].[ProductPicture] AS [ProductPicture], 
    [Limit1].[SlaDelivery] AS [SlaDelivery], 
    [Limit1].[ReplacedBy] AS [ReplacedBy], 
    [Limit1].[fkidDefaultOsRollIn] AS [fkidDefaultOsRollIn], 
    [Limit1].[fkidModelHardware1] AS [fkidModelHardware1]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[idAssetHardware] AS [idAssetHardware], 
        [Extent1].[UID] AS [UID], 
        [Extent1].[fkidAssetHardwareParent] AS [fkidAssetHardwareParent], 
        [Extent1].[fkidAssetHardwareParentPermanent] AS [fkidAssetHardwareParentPermanent], 
        [Extent1].[AssetTag] AS [AssetTag], 
        [Extent1].[SerialNumber] AS [SerialNumber], 
        [Extent1].[Hostname] AS [Hostname], 
        [Extent1].[Alias] AS [Alias], 
        [Extent1].[fkidModel] AS [fkidModel], 
        [Extent1].[fkidRoom] AS [fkidRoom], 
        [Extent1].[Nomad] AS [Nomad], 
        [Extent1].[ManyUsers] AS [ManyUsers], 
        [Extent1].[fkidDepartment] AS [fkidDepartment], 
        [Extent1].[fkidUserAD] AS [fkidUserAD], 
        [Extent1].[fkidStatus] AS [fkidStatus], 
        [Extent1].[EndOfLeaseDate] AS [EndOfLeaseDate], 
        [Extent1].[fkidOwner] AS [fkidOwner], 
        [Extent1].[Suspect] AS [Suspect], 
        [Extent1].[LastChecked] AS [LastChecked], 
        [Extent1].[Remark] AS [Remark], 
        [Extent1].[LastModifiedBy] AS [LastModifiedBy], 
        [Extent1].[LastModifiedOn] AS [LastModifiedOn], 
        [Extent1].[fkidAssetService] AS [fkidAssetService], 
        [Extent1].[SCCM_ResourceID] AS [SCCM_ResourceID], 
        [Extent1].[fkidOs] AS [fkidOs], 
        [Extent1].[fkidProfile] AS [fkidProfile], 
        [Extent1].[InvDate] AS [InvDate], 
        [Extent1].[fkidNetwork] AS [fkidNetwork], 
        [Extent1].[fkidAssetServiceWarranty] AS [fkidAssetServiceWarranty], 
        [Extent1].[MacAdress] AS [MacAdress], 
        [Extent1].[WarrantyExtensionYears] AS [WarrantyExtensionYears], 
        [Extent1].[fkidLeasingContract] AS [fkidLeasingContract], 
        [Extent1].[SAP] AS [SAP], 
        [Extent1].[Contact] AS [Contact], 
        [Join1].[idModel] AS [idModel], 
        [Join1].[ModelName] AS [ModelName], 
        [Join1].[PartNumber] AS [PartNumber], 
        [Join1].[fkidBrand] AS [fkidBrand], 
        [Join1].[fkidCategory] AS [fkidCategory], 
        [Join1].[fkidFamily] AS [fkidFamily], 
        [Join1].[fkidType] AS [fkidType], 
        [Join1].[Picture] AS [Picture], 
        [Join1].[RequestSerialNumber] AS [RequestSerialNumber], 
        [Join1].[AssetSuffix] AS [AssetSuffix], 
        [Join1].[BufferStock] AS [BufferStock], 
        [Join1].[SlavePermanent] AS [SlavePermanent], 
        [Join1].[ImportantForInv] AS [ImportantForInv], 
        [Join1].[ExcludeFromDashboard] AS [ExcludeFromDashboard], 
        [Join1].[DefaultWarrantyLengthYears] AS [DefaultWarrantyLengthYears], 
        [Join1].[ToFollowUp] AS [ToFollowUp], 
        [Join1].[ForceShowProfile] AS [ForceShowProfile], 
        [Join1].[ForceShowSvcDetails] AS [ForceShowSvcDetails], 
        [Join4].[idProductCode1] AS [idProductCode], 
        [Join4].[ProductDescription1] AS [ProductDescription], 
        [Join4].[Category1] AS [Category], 
        [Join4].[NeedDelivery1] AS [NeedDelivery], 
        [Join4].[fkidDealer1] AS [fkidDealer], 
        [Join4].[fkidModelHardware1] AS [fkidModelHardware], 
        [Join4].[fkidSoftwareCatalog1] AS [fkidSoftwareCatalog], 
        [Join4].[fkidServiceCatalog1] AS [fkidServiceCatalog], 
        [Join4].[ProductPicture1] AS [ProductPicture], 
        [Join4].[SlaDelivery1] AS [SlaDelivery], 
        [Join4].[ReplacedBy1] AS [ReplacedBy], 
        [Join4].[fkidDefaultOsRollIn1] AS [fkidDefaultOsRollIn], 
        [Join7].[fkidModelHardware2] AS [fkidModelHardware1]
        FROM    [dbo].[t_AssetsHardwares] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[idModel] AS [idModel], [Extent2].[ModelName] AS [ModelName], [Extent2].[PartNumber] AS [PartNumber], [Extent2].[fkidBrand] AS [fkidBrand], [Extent2].[fkidCategory] AS [fkidCategory], [Extent2].[fkidFamily] AS [fkidFamily], [Extent2].[fkidType] AS [fkidType], [Extent2].[Picture] AS [Picture], [Extent2].[RequestSerialNumber] AS [RequestSerialNumber], [Extent2].[AssetSuffix] AS [AssetSuffix], [Extent2].[BufferStock] AS [BufferStock], [Extent2].[SlavePermanent] AS [SlavePermanent], [Extent2].[ImportantForInv] AS [ImportantForInv], [Extent2].[ExcludeFromDashboard] AS [ExcludeFromDashboard], [Extent2].[DefaultWarrantyLengthYears] AS [DefaultWarrantyLengthYears], [Extent2].[ToFollowUp] AS [ToFollowUp], [Extent2].[ForceShowProfile] AS [ForceShowProfile], [Extent2].[ForceShowSvcDetails] AS [ForceShowSvcDetails]
            FROM  [dbo].[t_Models] AS [Extent2]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[t_MIT_Products] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent2].[idModel] = [Extent3].[FkidModelHardware]) AND ([Extent3].[FkidModelHardware] IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[fkidModel] = [Join1].[idModel]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[idProductCode] AS [idProductCode1], [Extent4].[ProductDescription] AS [ProductDescription1], [Extent4].[Category] AS [Category1], [Extent4].[NeedDelivery] AS [NeedDelivery1], [Extent4].[fkidDealer] AS [fkidDealer1], [Extent4].[fkidModelHardware] AS [fkidModelHardware1], [Extent4].[fkidSoftwareCatalog] AS [fkidSoftwareCatalog1], [Extent4].[fkidServiceCatalog] AS [fkidServiceCatalog1], [Extent4].[ProductPicture] AS [ProductPicture1], [Extent4].[SlaDelivery] AS [SlaDelivery1], [Extent4].[ReplacedBy] AS [ReplacedBy1], [Extent4].[fkidDefaultOsRollIn] AS [fkidDefaultOsRollIn1], [Extent4].[FkidModelHardware] AS [fkidModelHardware1], [Join3].[idModel]
            FROM  [dbo].[t_MIT_Products] AS [Extent4]
            INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent5].[idModel] AS [idModel]
                FROM  [dbo].[t_Models] AS [Extent5]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[t_MIT_Products] AS [Extent6] ON ([Extent5].[idModel] = [Extent6].[FkidModelHardware]) AND ([Extent6].[FkidModelHardware] IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Join3] ON [Extent4].[FkidModelHardware] = [Join3].[idModel] ) AS [Join4] ON [Extent1].[fkidModel] = [Join4].[idModel]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent7].[fkidModelHardware] AS [fkidModelHardware2], [Extent7].[FkidModelHardware] AS [fkidModelHardware2], [Join6].[idModel]
            FROM  [dbo].[t_MIT_Products] AS [Extent7]
            INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent8].[idModel] AS [idModel]
                FROM  [dbo].[t_Models] AS [Extent8]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[t_MIT_Products] AS [Extent9] ON ([Extent8].[idModel] = [Extent9].[FkidModelHardware]) AND ([Extent9].[FkidModelHardware] IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Join6] ON [Extent7].[FkidModelHardware] = [Join6].[idModel] ) AS [Join7] ON [Extent1].[fkidModel] = [Join7].[idModel]
        WHERE [Extent1].[idAssetHardware] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=134955
```

The following is the LINQ query which produces the error:

```
_unitOfWork.AssetHardwares.Include(ah => ah.Model)
       .Include(ah => ah.Model.MITProduct)
       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == assetHardwareId);
```

My mapping class:

```
using ITAM.Domain.MIT;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace ITAM.DAL.Mapping
{
    public class MITProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MITProduct>
    {
        public MITProductMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.Id)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            this.Property(t => t.ProductDescription)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            this.Property(t => t.ReplacedBy)
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("t_MIT_Products");
            this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("idProductCode");
            this.Property(t => t.ProductDescription).HasColumnName("ProductDescription");
            this.Property(t => t.Category).HasColumnName("Category");
            this.Property(t => t.NeedDelivery).HasColumnName("NeedDelivery");
            this.Property(t => t.FkidDealer).HasColumnName("fkidDealer");
            this.Property(t => t.FkidModelHardware).HasColumnName("fkidModelHardware");
            this.Property(t => t.FkidSoftwareCatalog).HasColumnName("fkidSoftwareCatalog");
            this.Property(t => t.FkidServiceCatalog).HasColumnName("fkidServiceCatalog");
            this.Property(t => t.ProductPicture).HasColumnName("ProductPicture");
            this.Property(t => t.SlaDelivery).HasColumnName("SlaDelivery");
            this.Property(t => t.ReplacedBy).HasColumnName("ReplacedBy");
            this.Property(t => t.FkidDefaultOsRollIn).HasColumnName("fkidDefaultOsRollIn");

            // Relationships
            this.HasOptional(t => t.SoftwareCatalog)
                .WithMany(t => t.MITProducts)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.FkidSoftwareCatalog);

            //If you want to consider the relationship between t_Models and t_MIT_Products as a one to many. (standard created by tool)
            //this.HasOptional(t => t.Model)
            //    .WithMany()
            //    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FkidModelHardware);

            //I've succeeded to consider the relationship between t_Models and t_MIT_Products as a one to one with the following syntax.
            //https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806344/One-to-zero-one-relation-in-entity-framework-code
            this.HasOptional(t => t.Model)
                .WithOptionalDependent(t => t.MITProduct).Map(x => x.MapKey("FkidModelHardware"));
        }
    }
}
```

When using explicit loading I don't have the problem:

```
//Solution: use explicit loading for loading the MITProduct   
//http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx
var assetHardware = _unitOfWork.AssetHardwares
                        .Include(ah => ah.Model)
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == assetHardwareId);

_unitOfWork.Entry(assetHardware.Model)
                        .Reference(m => m.MITProduct).Load();
```

Is this a bug in the query generation of LINQ?

Comment: .Include(ah => ah.Model.MITProduct) does already include ah.Model. remove the redundant include clause and see wether it works then.

Comment: The LINQ query 
<br>
_unitOfWork.AssetHardwares.Include(ah => ah.Model.MITProduct).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == assetHardwareId);

produces the same error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The column 'fkidModelHardware1' was specified multiple times for 'Join4'.
The column 'fkidModelHardware2' was specified multiple times for 'Join7'.

Comment: What version of EF?  Can you produce a simplified repro?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3.  I've created a sample project which reproduces the error https://1drv.ms/a/s!BJ4TaVsx8r2IbQy5MqsSKu0hbeE

Comment: Is the sample project helpfull for diagnose?